# How does an admin grant access to an app?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have made a web app that using Microsoft Graph and the scopes `profile`,  `openid`, `email` and `User.Read`. This works fine.

I now want to include `offline_access`, `User.Read`, `Mail.Send`, `Calendars.ReadWrite`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, `User.Read.All`, `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Files.Read`, `Files.ReadWrite`, and  `Sites.Read.All` scopes.

When trying to login I get the message:

> You can't access this application.
>
> Tutorial Sample App needs permission to access resources in your organisation that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

I registered the app at `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/` and have these Graph Permissions set:

[image]

Using PHP, I use the following

```php
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
const CLIENT_ID          = 'xxx';
const CLIENT_SECRET      = 'xxx';
const REDIRECT_URI       = 'xxxx';
const AUTHORITY_URL      = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common';
const AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT = '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT     = '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
const SCOPES             = 'profile openid email offline_access User.Read Mail.Send Calendars.ReadWrite Directory.ReadWrite.All Directory.AccessAsUser.All User.Read.All Files.ReadWrite.All Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Sites.Read.All';
```

and to create the `authorisationUrl`

```
$authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
```

So, how can I get admin to grant access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain Admin Consent, you need to have an Admin for the tenant authenticate against the `/adminconsent`. The prototype for this URL is (line-break for readability only):

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?
client_id=[APPLICATION ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT URI]
```

I've written a blog post on this that will help walk you through how this works: [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/).

Comment: Hi Marc. Thanks for the article. Still I am not clear how to rectify the error.