# Authenticating O365 application with Customized Administrator isn't working

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I am trying to authenticate one O365 application (enterprise application) using a customized administrator (not a global administrator) with SharePoint Admin, Exchange Online Admin, Reports Admin and User Management Admin roles.

The app asks for User.ReadWrite, SharePoint Files.ReadWrite and Mail.ReadWrite like scopes

On authentication, I am getting the following error -

---

**Need admin approval**

*XXXXXXXXXX App needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.*

---

It works if I add global administrator role to the user from AzureAD.

Do we always need the global administrator role (or user) to authenticate an application that might needs some permissions that require admin consent (delegated) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does an admin grant access to an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178039/how-does-an-admin-grant-access-to-an-app)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur So, the user I created is actually an customized administrator only. So, I suppose it already has the admin access

Comment: In general, users do not have any more access through Graph than they otherwise would. In terms of Consent, however, I believe only a Global Admin can self-consent to scopes that require Admin Consent.